# Mina usage of DatagramConnector does not work

Tags: java, apache-mina

I have a tcp client, which is based on the mina (V2.0.21 and J8) framework. It is working fine.

Here is the minimal example:

```java
    private static IoConnector connector;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    
        connector = new NioSocketConnector();
        
        connector.getFilterChain().addLast( "logger", new LoggingFilter() );
        connector.getFilterChain().addLast( "codec", new ProtocolCodecFilter( new TextLineCodecFactory( Charset.forName( "UTF-8" ))));
    
        connector.setHandler(new Handler());
    
        try {
            ConnectFuture connFuture = connector.connect(new InetSocketAddress("x.x.x.x", 9999));
            connFuture.awaitUninterruptibly();
            connFuture.getSession();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("sleep.");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }
    }
```

This is my handler:

```java
    public class Handler implements IoHandler {
        @Override
        public void messageReceived(IoSession session, Object message) throws Exception {
            String str = (String)message;
            System.out.println("->" + str);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void sessionCreated(IoSession session) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("CREATED.");
            
        }
    
        @Override
        public void sessionOpened(IoSession session) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("OPENED.");
            
        }
        ...
    }
```

Now, i have changed the line

```java
        connector = new NioSocketConnector();
```

to

```java
        connector = new NioDatagramConnector();
```

to be able to receive data via UDP.

If i now send packages via UDP (e.g. using a network test tool) to the port 9999 this program will not receive anything anymore. But i can see the log information, that the session was opened and created. Can somebody explain, why UDP is not working (to be more specific: messageReceived() is not called), but TCP does?

UPDATE: As a test tool i am using this method here:

```java
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getByName("x.x.x.x");
            int port = 9999;
            String s = "Message";
            byte[] data = s.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( data, data.length, ia, port );
            DatagramSocket toSocket = new DatagramSocket();
            toSocket.send( packet );
            toSocket.close();
            System.out.println("Send.");
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the secret is to know, that in UDP case both, the "connector" and "acceptor" side is handled by the class NioDatagramAcceptor.

This piece of code does the magic for the UDP-"connector"-side:

```java
    NioDatagramAcceptor acceptor = new NioDatagramAcceptor();
    acceptor.getFilterChain().addLast( "logger", new LoggingFilter() );
    acceptor.getFilterChain().addLast( "codec", new ProtocolCodecFilter( new TextLineCodecFactory( Charset.forName( "UTF-8" ))));
    acceptor.setHandler(new Handler());
    acceptor.bind(new InetSocketAddress(9999));
```